# Cordova signing android application : not working with build.json

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, cordova-5.0.0

I work on cordova 5.x and i would generate a signing apk.

I start to use build.json at the root of the cordova project with certificat credentials :

```
{
  "android": {
   "debug": {
      "keystore": "cert.keystore",
      "storePassword": "*****",
      "alias": "1",
      "password" : "*****",
      "keystoreType": "PKCS12"
    },
```

It create a release-signing.properties in platforms/android like that :

```
key.store=..\\..\\cert.keystore
key.alias=1
key.store.password=*****
key.alias.password=*****
key.store.type=PKCS12
```

But i have an error : cert.keystore": DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big (because it don't understand the key is a PKCS12 type)

After i write my own release-signing.properties like that :

```
storeFile=..\\..\\cert.keystore
storePassword=*****
keystoreType=PKCS12
keyAlias=1
keyPassword=*****
```

And it works ... so i don't understand why the first solution doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it's the name : keystoreType = keystore.type

Comment: are you trying to generate a release build?  It seems like your build.json only specifies configs for a debug build.  I only have a release config in my build.json file.  When I run cordova build android --release, it generates the android-release.apk file in the appropriate directories

Comment: I use release. The problem is the config file, android compile don't understand the cert key format. So i use another solution with "jarsigner" and zipalign, it's work

Answer (score 5):

On Cordova 5, there is no need to manually edit this "release-signing.properties" file.

You just need to save the "build.json" and the "cert.keystore" files at the root of your project (exactly like you already do). After that, run the command on cordova CLI:

`cordova build android --release`.

Furthermore, you should never touch any file inside the platform folder. In my case, I don't even trace them on my git repo.